# Does protobuf-net support Windows RT?

Tags: windows-runtime, protobuf-net

Is it possible to use the [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/) library in an application that targets Windows RT?  I tried adding it via NuGet to my project but I receive this error:

```
Successfully installed 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.480'.
Successfully uninstalled 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.480'.
Install failed. Rolling back...
Could not install package 'protobuf-net 2.0.0.480'. You are trying to install this package into a project that targets '.NETCore,Version=v4.5', but the package does not contain any assembly references that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a newer version. Version 594 has support for 4.5.
In the package manager console (Tools->Library Package Manager->Package Manager Console) run:

PM> Install-Package protobuf-net -Version 2.0.0.594

Or download it from the project web site.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the more recent builds have full support for .NETCore (aka "WinRT", "Windows Store Applications", or "Metro", or "Modern UI", or whatever they want to call it today). As Eli notes, you can obtain it *by specific version*, or you can get it from the google-code download.

Note that for the best performance it is recommended to use ["precompile", the new precompiler](http://marcgravell.blogspot.co.uk/2012/07/introducing-protobuf-net-precompiler.html), because .NETCore has no support for meta-programming: without this, it will be using reflection at runtime, and will not be anywhere near as fast as it can be. This is included in the google-code download.

Comment: Thanks for the performance tip and your work on this project.  On a side note I'm finding it very difficult to Google issues related to WinRT development precisely because there are too many synonyms.

Comment: hi Marc. I want ask you I post my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19537421/windows-store-app-certification-failed/19538137?noredirect=1#comment28990347_19538137 do you have any idea where can be problem?

Comment: @PavolFranek if you read the previous comment, ignore it; there seems to be some confusion here between protobuf-csharp-port and protobuf-net; they are different libraries, and I can only directly comment on protobuf-net - but: that has full support for windows store apps (and android / iphone if you are using the xamarin tools or similar). For protobuf-csharp-port, you would have to ask Jon Skeet.