# Windows store app certification failed

Tags: windows-8, windows-store-apps, certificate, protocol-buffers

I try publish my windows store app to market but I get status FAILED in process certification. Here is image: [link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/nvic8c0ph9s57qk/cerFail.PNG)

Im using google protocol buffer port from here: [link](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-csharp-port/)

Anyone have the same problem? Or anyone know where can be problem. I have added protocolbuffer.dll to references and app works great there are not problem.

Comment: We haven't tried to build protobuf-csharp-port as a PCL targeting Windows Store. We may do so in the future.

Comment: ok so which protocol buffer I can use in my windows store app? I cannot switch to different protocol technology because we use the same protocol on android and iOS and they dont have problem. Can I use this>https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/downloads/list ?

Comment: You should be fine with protobuf-net. As Marc has said, that's the same *protocol*, just a different implementation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot comment on protobuf-csharp-port

However! protobuf-net supports windows-store apps; within protobuf-net there are different dlls for different target platforms. If you are using NuGet it should pick the right one for you. If you are using the google-code download, make sure you use the dll from the `Full/netcore45` or `CoreOnly/netcore45` folders (see "What files Do I Need.txt" for more information); "netcore" is the name of the framework that is used by [windows-store-apps](/questions/tagged/windows-store-apps). You could *also* probably use `CoreOnly/portable` or `Full/portable`, but `netcore45` may have internal optimizations (using APIs that exist in windows-store, but not on all "portable" targets).

Additionally, note that for *optimum* performance on windows-store, you would need to use the precompiler (again, see "What files Do I Need.txt" for more information).

Answer (score 1):

**UPDATE 1**

Try [protobuf-net](https://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/)

[Does protobuf-net support Windows RT?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13188331/1230188)

Google protocol buffer port is not valid Windows Store supported APIs. You need to remove it & find alternative of it.

Comment: But we are using google protocol buffer on more platforms like iOS and android and there are not problem. But I want to ask is there any possible way how I can use this protocol in Wind RT. For example if I import all classes from protocol.dll and use it this way can work? Its very important for me find any way how I can stay under google protocol. Do you have any idea?

Comment: thx for tip but I m using the same protocol which support RT and protocol work great in app. There is only problem with app certification.(

Comment: Yes I know. Many devs are facing kinda issues. MSFT should allow this to develop generous apps.

Comment: @PavolFranek to clarify: protobuf-net **is** using the google protobuf format - it is just a different library to achieve the same thing; and if you are using the xamarin tools, protobuf-net should work fine for android / iOS too

Comment: So I use NET protocol and I get this: https://www.dropbox.com/s/0oc2uv9saf5t3ry/cer4.PNG What I do: 1. download protobuf-net r668, 2.From folder Precompile I add dll protobuf-net.dll to project folder and set reference in project, 3. In folder ProtoGen I open cmd and with comand I do my classes(UniPB-main proto, desriptor.proto and wsAuth-my second proto file) when I have classes I add these classes to project. Almost all generated classes work only I have problem with serialize see in image.